# How to add a heatmap to a figure sharing a datetime x-axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, seaborn

I've made a histogram with a DatetimeIndex on the x-axis, but I have trouble adding a heatmap to the plot that shares the same x-axis. On the other hand, adding a lineplot that shares the x-axis works well:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import HourLocator, DateFormatter
import seaborn as sns

# create DatetimeIndex with all hours of the day
datetimes = pd.date_range(start="2015-01-10 00:00",end="2015-01-10 23:59", freq="1H")

# create values for the all the plots
df = pd.DataFrame({"datetimes": datetimes,
                   "hist_values": np.random.randint(10, 20, size=24), 
                   "lineplot_values": np.random.uniform(20,50,size=24), 
                   "heatmap_values": np.random.random(24)})

# create a histogram
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,5))

sns.histplot(x=df["datetimes"], weights=df["hist_values"], bins=24, color="green", ax=ax1)

# set x-labels
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(HourLocator([0,6,12,18])) # xlabels for hour 0, 6, 12 and 18
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%H:%M")) # show datetime object in hour:minute form

# add the lineplot
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.lineplot(x=df["datetimes"], y=df["lineplot_values"], color="darkblue", ax=ax2)
```

The result is this:
[histogram_lineplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPIiM.png)

However, when I add a heatmap to the same figure sharing the x-axis, this happens:

```
df_heatmap_date = df[["datetimes","heatmap_values"]].set_index("datetimes").transpose()

# add the heatmap
ax3 = ax1.twinx()
sns.heatmap(df_heatmap_date, cmap="BuGn_r", cbar=False, yticklabels=False, ax=ax3)
ax3.set_ylim(0,20)
```

The result is this (as you can see, it doesn't work):
[histogram_lineplot_heatmap_fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHyb7.png)

If the x-axis is set to **hours** (integers), rather than a **DatetimeIndex**, it does work properly:

```
# create a histogram
fig2, ax4 = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,5))

sns.histplot(x=df.index, weights=df["hist_values"], bins=24, color="green", ax=ax4)

# add the lineplot
ax5 = ax4.twinx()
sns.lineplot(x=df.index, y=df["lineplot_values"], color="darkblue", ax=ax5)

# add the heatmap
df_heatmap_hour = df[["heatmap_values"]].transpose()
ax6 = ax4.twinx()
sns.heatmap(df_heatmap_hour, cmap="Greens", cbar=False, yticklabels=False, ax=ax6)
ax6.set_ylim(0,20)
```

The result is this:
[histogram_lineplot_heatmap_succes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59ao1.png)

How can I add the heatmap to the plots while still having a DatetimeIndex as x-axis?

Comment: `ax4.set_xticks(df.index, df.datetimes.astype(str))` last would work, or `ax4.set_xticklabels(df.datetimes.astype(str), rotation=90)`

Comment: See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRNvb.png). The tick locations for the axis of a barplot are indexed from 0. If you try to plot a datetime, the datetime is converted to a number the is much larger than the given tick locations, so the "heatmap" segments will not correspond to the bar locations .